# Spark ERROR network.ConnectionManager:

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm getting the below error while submiting spark submit query. can any one please suggest how to resolve this issue

```
15/02/18 12:06:17 INFO network.ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@5173169
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:386)
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139)
15/02/18 12:06:17 ERROR network.ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(bkcttplpd037.verizon.com,39010) not found
15/02/18 12:06:17 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7a73a542
15/02/18 12:06:17 INFO network.ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7a73a542
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139)
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterActor: MapOutputTrackerActor stopped!
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Selector thread was interrupted!
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(abc02.com,49740)
15/02/18 12:06:18 ERROR network.ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(abc01.com,49740) not found
15/02/18 12:06:18 WARN network.ConnectionManager: All connections not cleaned up
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO network.ConnectionManager: ConnectionManager stopped
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.15/02/18 12:06:18 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
```